# principles and practice using C++, how to exit a loop

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and I'm studying c++ using "Programming: principles and practice using C++, 
for reference I'm at chapter 4 and I have some doubts on the example at 4.6.3 and 4.6.4, I'm gonna paste part of a  code and then explaing what puzzles me, it's likely very basic:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
        words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
}
```

now I'm on windows 7 and I am using microsoft visual studio 2017,
if I run the above code I can keep on entering words but I don't know how to "exit" the for loop and arrive to the "cout" part. All the examples in these 2 sections of chapter 4 have that problem (for me), once I run these codes I get stuck in the for loop and that's it, now I know I could use and if statement and decide to use a particular character, say 0, to exit the loop and run the rest of the code, but the author does not and that tells me that there might be some shortkey to "exit" the loop without closing the program.

Comment: Did you try not entering anything?

Comment: hi, well I tried entering backspace or just pressing enter but it simply goes to the line above (how do you say that in proper english?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once done entering strings, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> if on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> if on Linux followed by yet another <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That will send the EOF character to your input stream causing the `cin >> temp;` condition to (implicitly) evaluate to `false` thus exiting the [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for). The above can be converted to use the [while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    char c = 'y';
    std::string tempstr;
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    while (std::cin && c == 'y'){
        std::cout << "Enter string: " << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, tempstr);
        words.push_back(tempstr);
        std::cout << "Another entry? y/n: ";
        std::cin >> c;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think ```ctrl+c``` is to close a program

Comment: Ctrl+C would send SIGINT to the process, why is not treated as an input. If you meant to send EOF, it's Ctrl+D on UNIX, Ctrl+Z on Windows.

Comment: This will terminate the program unless OP implements something to handle SIGINT. OP wants to exit the loop without closing the program.

Comment: @ Ron, so while I was delivering pizzas (lol) I read your reply and at first I  said to my self "I tried Ctrl+Z and it simply closed the program" or so I thought...then I had an "epiphany", in Windows you have to add 

keep_window_open();  

in order to keep the executables from closing in a split second...

so to cut a long story short Ctrl+Z works, 
Windows users just have to remember to add keep_window_open(); to the codes. Thanks a lot for your time.